# AzCopy - how to copy ALL blobs from one storage account to another recursively starting from root$

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I used AzCopy for copying container from one storage account to another. But how can I copy **everything** recursively from one to another? Tried many params - no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, AzCopy is designed for copying container or directory. If you want to copy all the containers, you'd need to list the contains within storage account by yourself and call AzCopy with listed containers one by one.

Update: Now it cab be easily done - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#copy-containers-directories-and-blobs

Comment: Too bad. This is an essential functionality

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10).

```
azcopy copy "https://source_storage.blob.core.windows.net/source_container/source_SAS_Key" "https://target_storage.blob.core.windows.net/target_container/target_SAS_Key" --recursive=true
```